# How do I change where database diagram relationship lines attach in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench, database-diagrams

Sometimes, MySQL Workbench makes some strange choices about where table relationship lines get attached.  For example, two vertical lines would be better in the following:

[image: Connections look like an H with crossover instead of two vertical lines]

For a while, these boxes (representing tables) had two vertical lines between them, and the crossover happened when other boxes were added elsewhere in the diagram, and things got moved around a bit.

Is there a way to say something like "this line should go to this attachment point"?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to specify attachment points. That layout algorithm has a few flaws.